# How to represent a Java-collection-valued attribute in UML?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Hello I'm new to UML so I got stucked.

Here's the code:

```
private ArrayList<Blocks> blocks = new ArrayList<Blocks>();
```

So I've been looking for ways to properly place that code into UML but I can't understand it.
So here is some things that I'ved tried but I don't really know if correct

Here the graphic alternatives:
  [image][image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwY6K.jpg)

So which is correct and is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In one sense, anything is correct in a UML diagram provided that the people (or tools) that read the diagram understand what you mean.

In another sense, it is more conventional / appropriate to use UML syntax.  UML is design language not a programming language.  If you are trying to using programming language (i.e. Java) syntax for types, declarations, etc in a UML diagram you are (probably) missing the point of UML.  (A UML tool is likely to object to you using Java syntax, but it depends on how closely / deeply it implements the formal UML syntax and metamodel.)

In this case, I think the most appropriate way to write that would be:

```
  - block : Block[]
```

or

```
  - block : Block[1..*]
```

The fact that you want to use `ArrayList<Block>` to implement the multi-value is an implementation detail.  It doesn't belong in the UML diagram.  (In my opinion.)

But there is a (possible) third alternative.  Add `Block` to your UML diagram as a class, and model the relationship using an Association.

Comment: So the declaration using new in java isn't really included in the UML by the convention without following the third option?

Comment: By convention, you don't include programming language specific syntax in UML.  Not with the third alternative either!  However, unless you are going to use this UML to generate code, you can probably ignore that convention.  (If you use a tool, you need to write your UML models according to the requirements of the tool ...)

Comment: @Sapphirex use an association (third alternative) with the appropriate multiplicity, then you can just stereotype it with <<ArrayList>> if you think it is better to indicate how the relation is supported:implemented

Comment: Tying a UML Property to a UML Association when the Property type is a UML Class is generally a superior way of modeling. The reason is that a human can instantaneously absorb the possible relationships among instances, without decoding any text. Such a model is far easier to review and validate, which is part of what makes UML useful.

Answer (score 2):

UML Class Diagrams can be used both for making

1. programming-language-agnostic *design models* and
2. programming-language-specific *implementation models*.

In a ***design model***, you would define `blocks` as a multi-valued reference property referencing a set/list of instances of a class `Block` (that is, `Block`would be the range of the property `blocks`), or, equivalently, as the name of a non-functional association end of an association between `Class`and `Block`, as in

```
blocks: Block[0..*]
```

Such a reference property could be implemented in any OOP language according to the available idioms. E.g., in Java, it could be implemented as a `Set`- or `List`-valued property.

In an OO ***implementation model***, like a *Java Entity class model* or a *C# class model*, you could use any suitable built-in template collection class, such as `Set<Block>` or `List<Block>`, as the range of the property `blocks`:

```
blocks: Set<Block>
```

Notice that normally, in a Java class model, you wouldn't use `ArrayList<Block>` as the range of the property `blocks`, but rather `List<Block>`, in order not to prematurely exclude the choice of implementing the property with `LinkedList<Block>`.

Comment: You do not know the reasons why the OP uses _ArrayList_,  how can you say _you wouldn't use ArrayList<Block>_ from nothing ? _ArrayList_ is a _built-in template collection class_ : (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html]. I am close to DV your answer (but I do not)

Comment: +1 for highlighting the difference: design vs implementation. Maybe worth to mention that neither ArrayList nor any other language-specific containers do not belong to UML unless you use the appropriate profile ;-)